# Writer.WriteLine System.FormatException

Tags: c#, string, streamwriter

I have some lines that are read from a text file, have some parsing performed on them and are then rewritten to disc using this loop:

```
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> kvp in FileLinesDictionary)
                {
                    string fName;
                    if ((kvp.Key != null) && ((fName = Path.GetFileName(GetPathPair(kvp.Key).CurrentPath)) != null))
                    {

                        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(MainForm.MidG, fName));
                        Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
                        foreach (string line in kvp.Value)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(line,utf8);
                        }
                        writer.Flush();
                        writer.Close();
                    }
                }
```

For some reason this appears to occasionally cause a System.FormatException saying that my strings are not in the correct format.

One string in particular that causes this issue is:

`"        . userdata \"END_FOXV=  ^aname=^alevel=20^action=EXECUTE^required=0^cmd=almack_c {CMP}^\""`

Any advice on how to fix this issue would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not, I pressed enter instead of `#` whilst entering the tags, fixed immediately

Comment: Additional hint to the closing: "{CMP}" is causing your issue.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I'll work on a way to escape those

Comment: Just in case it is not obvious, you simply have to duplicate them ("{{CMP}}").

Comment: Just remove the `utf8` parameter - it has no effect anyway. Instead, use one of the `StreamWriter` constructor overloads that allow you to pass an encoding.

Comment: Thanks @Christian.K, sorry for the dupe, the posts I looked at dealt with the issue in a non relevant way, the one you linked however is ideal. Ivan, I need utf8 formatting for later on in the program, but thanks!

Comment: @JamesHughes that overload doesn't do that (no overlaod of writeline does that). You'll need one of the constructors of StreamWriter to achieve that

Comment: Oh? What does my overload do? I'll have a look at fixing my StreamWriter then

Comment: Format an object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e89z0w8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Cheers @rene got that fixed, thanks everyone!